# Want some knowledge about Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code i have copied this code from somewhere to learn about Array. i have some problem with that the code is working perfect but i want to know that
in code `var ascendingArray = new Array(10);`what is mean by `(10)` and what is this line doing here `employees = employees.concat(newEmployees);` means what is mean by this line.
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Array</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var employees = new Array();
employees[0]='d';
employees[1]='b';
var newEmployees = new Array();
newEmployees[0]='c';
newEmployees[1]='a';
var ascendingArray = new Array(10);
var decendingArray = new Array(10);
document.writeln('<h3>Employee Names:</h3>');
document.writeln('<br>List Of Employee:<br/>');
employees = employees.concat(newEmployees);
for(var i=0; i < employees.length; i++)
{
    document.write("<ul><li>"+employees[i] + "</ul>");
}
ascendingArray=employees.sort();
decendingArray=ascendingArray.reverse();
document.writeln('<br>List of Employees in decending order:');
for(var i=0; i< decendingArray.length; i++)
{
    document.write("<ul><li>" + decendingArray[i] + "</ul>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are looking for can be found on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with

```
new Array(10)
```

you can give the array an initial size of 10.

```
employees.concat(newEmployees)
```

means: put the two arrays together to one single array

Comment: ok sir what kind of limit can you please define briefly in simple words.

Comment: sry my comment got stuck... what I said was: there is no "limit" in defining the size of an Array in Javascript. The parameter n (p.e. n=10) just tells the interpreter to reserve space for n elements. There can be more than n elements in the Array. If you know, how many elements will be in you array, you can define it during the initialization, but it's not a "must-have". And be careful in other languages (C, Java, Pascal, ...) where the parameter defines the **maximum** number of elements in that array.

Comment: ok. I revoke my statement, that there is any "reservation of memory", because it really just sets the length attribute to the given parameter. This is a real strange bevhaviour because when you define an array with p.e. size 4, add 2 elements and then iterate from 0 to length you get two "undefined" values back, which is not what I would expect when using the length attribute in a foor loop.

Answer (score 0):

(10) is number of elements which tells to compiler that it has to allocate memory for 10  elements

Comment: It would not allocate memory for 10 elements, it would simply assign the value to length attribute of the array.

Comment: sir can you tell me in simple words because i am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
says that `new Array(length)` creates a new empty `Array` and then assigns the `length` property of it to the `length` passed, so i do not think it allocates memory for 10 "whatever" type of objects.

concat is a method to append some new values to the existing array.